# What is the format of LSN in DMS for DB2 Endpoint?

Tags: pyspark, db2, dms

I am trying to migrate data from **DB2** to `AWS S3` using `Amazon DMS CDC task`.

I want to capture current LSN (Log Sequence Number) and add it as a new column in all tables. I have tried below approached and it is working fine for **DB2 v9.7.0.2 with Fix Pack 2** but when I try the same approach with **DB2 v10.5.0.7 with Fix Pack 7** then it gives value in a different format that I am not understanding.

**Approach**

I have added below transformation for all tables which add new column "LSN_Number"

```
{
      "rule-type": "transformation",
      "rule-id": "2",
      "rule-name": "2",
      "rule-target": "column",
      "object-locator": {
          "schema-name": "%",
          "table-name": "%"
      },
      "rule-action": "add-column",
      "value": "LSN_Number",
      "expression": "$AR_H_STREAM_POSITION",
      "data-type": {
          "type": "string",
          "length": 50
      }
    }
```

Value of LSN_Number column with **DB2 v9.7.0.2 with Fix Pack 2** is as below (expected)

```
0000000000000000006BD1E6BD1ED46BC2
000000000000000000000006BD1ED4AAFF
000000000000000000000006BD1ED54B82
000000000000000000000006BD1ED585CD
000000000000000000000006BD1ED61E74
```

But the value of LSN_Number column with **DB2 v10.5.0.7 with Fix Pack 7** is as below

```
010000000003AD0AD500000000360A8D38|0200000000000000000000002E3808795F
010000000003AD0AFF00000000360A8E38|0200000000000000000000002E3808F81F
010000000003AD133300000000360AF312|0200000000000000000000002E38405DB5
```

what is the difference between both format and how can I parse (010000000003AD0AD500000000360A8D38|0200000000000000000000002E3808795F)it with PySpark.

Comment: Db2 v10.5 increased the LSN size from 6 bytes to 8 bytes. See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.api.doc/doc/c0053836.html

Comment: Thanks, but that still not giving an answer to my question why there is Pipe in the result and what that mean?

Comment: Where's the source code for pulling from Db2 logs? API db2ReadLogNoConn returns startLSN, endLSN / firstReadLSN /nextStartLSN.